# How can I get rid of a part of the given plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, plot-themes

Using this code

```
A := Cos[3 y] + (7 Sin[3 y])/(2 y) + (-Cos[x] + Cos[2 y]) Csc[ 2 y] Sin[3 y];
B := (Cos[2 y] - Cos[x]) Csc[2 y] + Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 y] + (2 - y Cos[x] Csc[2 y]))^2];
F := (Cos[2 y] - Cos[x]) Csc[2 y] - Sqrt[-1 + (Cos[3 y] + (2 - y Cos[x] Csc[2 y]))^2];
p = Plot[1.6 , {y, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.02]], PlotRange -> {0, 1.7}];

Module[{colorsDot = {Black, Green, White}, 
  colorsLine = {Orange, Black, Green}, 
  pairs = Subsets[{" A ", " B ", " F "}, {2}], plt, pts}, 
 Show[Show[p,  plt = Plot[Evaluate[ToExpression[#[[1]]] /. x -> -4], {y, 0, 3}, 
       PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}, PlotStyle -> #[[2]],  PlotPoints -> 1000], 
     Graphics[{{PointSize[0.04], #[[3]], pts = Point@Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plt], 
        pts /. {y_, x_?NumericQ} :> {y, 1.6}}}],  PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
     ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, 10}, {Automatic, 20}}] & /@ 
   Transpose[{pairs, Subsets[colorsLine, {2}], colorsDot}]]]
```

I get the plot number $1$.

[image]

**Question:**

> How can I get rid of the curves $A,B,F$, i.e. the green, orange, and black curves (I can set the opacity of them to zero, but cannot get rid of those intersection points)? in addition to having those green and black points over the blue line (instead of behind it; actually, I change their order in `Show` but it gives an error)? I mean something like the plot number $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a minimal change to your code,

1. replace `,` with `;` after `plt = Plot[...]` and after `pts = Point@...`,  and
2. move `p` outside the inner `Show` (that is, replace `Show[Show[p, stuff]]` with `Show[p, Show[stuff]]`)

to get

[image]